# Data Annotation Validation from .net Standard Class Library in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-annotations

I have class library in .net Standard 2.0 decorated with Data Annotation and database operations. I wanted to use same class library across all platform e.g. WPF, Asp.net Core, Web Api, Xamarin.Forms for Android, iOS & UWP.

This library is working fine with WPF, Asp.Net Core & Web Api but same validation is not showing error message in Xamarin.Forms for Android, iOS & UWP.

Model Definition in Class Library:

```
public class UserLogin : NotificationObject
{
  [DbRequired]
  [Display(Name = "USER NAME", Prompt = "ENTER USER NAME")]
  public string User_Name
  {
    get { return GetValue(() => User_Name); }
    set { SetValue(() => User_Name, value); }
  }

  [Display(Name = "PASSWORD", Prompt = "ENTER PASSWORD")]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [DbRequired]
  public string User_Password
  {
    get { return GetValue(() => User_Password); }
    set { SetValue(() => User_Password, value); }
  }
}
```

I want to validation Xamarin.Forms input form with data annotation binding in Model. Please help me out of this. Please suggest, if some best practice is there and what I am missing.

Comment: You can refer to this link:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/validate-input-in-xamarin-forms-using-inotifydataerrorinfo-custom-behaviors-effects-and-prism/ there is some simple about the validation and data annotations in xamarin forms.

Comment: Hi @LeonLu Thanks for your response.

I have tried your suggested method but my scenario is quite different and it is not working in my scenario. I have .net Class Library on nuget and same can be install in xamarin.forms and use it.

**If validation base and model is created locally then it's working but when it's called from class library, it's not working. 
**

Comment: Xamarin just support INotifyDataErrorInfo to complement the traditional approach of using Behaviors. If you use other achievement, it cannot be supported, This issue is reported in github.https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/450#issuecomment-431028345